# keep getting "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') "

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native, and I have been able to get a gig on a new project. However, I can not seem to navigate from my onboarding screen as I keep getting the error undefined is not an object.

> evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate'

I have been on this for about a week, and I have been unable to find a solution. Below are my source codes.

Index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => App);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import OnBoardingScreen from './src/components/onboarding/OnBoardingScreen';
import Home from './src/components/Home';

const OnBoardingRoutes = StackNavigator({
    OnBoardingScreen:
    {
        screen: OnBoardingScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        },
    },
    Home:
    {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        },
    },
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'OnBoardingScreen'
    }
);

const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
    OnBoardingScreen:
    {
        screen: OnBoardingScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        },
    },
    Home:
    {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        },
    },
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home'
    }
);

type Props = {};
class App extends Component<Props> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <OnBoardingRoutes />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

swiper.js(onboarding)

```
/**
 * Swiper
 * Renders a swipable set of screens passed as children,
 * pagination indicators and a OnBoardingButton to swipe through screens
 * or to get out of the flow when the last screen is reached
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Dimensions,       // Detects screen dimensions
    Platform,         // Detects platform running the app
    ScrollView,       // Handles navigation between screens
    StyleSheet,       // CSS-like styles
    View,             // Container component
} from 'react-native';
import OnBoardingButton from '../buttons/OnBoardingButton';
import Home from '../Home';

// Detect screen width and height
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Swiper extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    }

    // Props for ScrollView component
    static defaultProps = {
        // Arrange screens horizontally
        horizontal: true,
        // Scroll exactly to the next screen, instead of continous scrolling
        pagingEnabled: true,
        // Hide all scroll indicators
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
        // Do not bounce when the end is reached
        bounces: false,
        // Do not scroll to top when the status bar is tapped
        scrollsToTop: false,
        // Remove offscreen child views
        removeClippedSubviews: true,
        // Do not adjust content behind nav-, tab- or toolbars automatically
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets: false,
        // Fisrt is screen is active
        index: 0
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.home = this.home.bind(this);
    }

    home() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    }

    /**
     * Render Continue or Done OnBoardingButton
     */

    renderOnBoardingButton = () => {
        const lastScreen = this.state.index === this.state.total - 1;
        return (
            <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={[styles.OnBoardingButtonWrapper, styles.fullScreen]}>
                {lastScreen
                    // Show this OnBoardingButton on the last screen
                    // TODO: Add a handler that would send a user to your app after onboarding is complete
                    ? <OnBoardingButton text="Start Now" onPress={() => this.home()} />
                    // Or this one otherwise
                    : <OnBoardingButton text="Continue" onPress={() => this.swipe()} />
                }
            </View>
        );
    }

    state = this.initState(this.props);

    /**
     * Initialize the state
     */
    initState(props) {
        // Get the total number of slides passed as children
        const total = props.children ? props.children.length || 1 : 0,
            // Current index
            index = total > 1 ? Math.min(props.index, total - 1) : 0,
            // Current offset
            offset = width * index;

        const state = {
            total,
            index,
            offset,
            width,
            height,
        };

        // Component internals as a class property,
        // and not state to avoid component re-renders when updated
        this.internals = {
            isScrolling: false,
            offset
        };

        return state;
    }

    /**
     * Scroll begin handler
     * @param {object} e native event
     */
    onScrollBegin = e => {
        // Update internal isScrolling state
        this.internals.isScrolling = true;
    }

    /**
     * Scroll end handler
     * @param {object} e native event
     */
    onScrollEnd = e => {
        // Update internal isScrolling state
        this.internals.isScrolling = false;

        // Update index
        this.updateIndex(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset
            ? e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
            // When scrolled with .scrollTo() on Android there is no contentOffset
            : e.nativeEvent.position * this.state.width
        );
    }

    /*
     * Drag end handler
     * @param {object} e native event
     */
    onScrollEndDrag = e => {
        const { contentOffset: { x: newOffset } } = e.nativeEvent,
            { children } = this.props,
            { index } = this.state,
            { offset } = this.internals;

        // Update internal isScrolling state
        // if swiped right on the last slide
        // or left on the first one
        if (offset === newOffset &&
            (index === 0 || index === children.length - 1)) {
            this.internals.isScrolling = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update index after scroll
     * @param {object} offset content offset
     */
    updateIndex = (offset) => {
        const state = this.state,
            diff = offset - this.internals.offset,
            step = state.width;
        let index = state.index;

        // Do nothing if offset didn't change
        if (!diff) {
            return;
        }

        // Make sure index is always an integer
        index = parseInt(index + Math.round(diff / step), 10);

        // Update internal offset
        this.internals.offset = offset;
        // Update index in the state
        this.setState({
            index
        });
    }

    /**
     * Swipe one slide forward
     */
    swipe = () => {
        // Ignore if already scrolling or if there is less than 2 slides
        if (this.internals.isScrolling || this.state.total < 2) {
            return;
        }

        const state = this.state,
            diff = this.state.index + 1,
            x = diff * state.width,
            y = 0;

        // Call scrollTo on scrollView component to perform the swipe
        this.scrollView && this.scrollView.scrollTo({ x, y, animated: true });

        // Update internal scroll state
        this.internals.isScrolling = true;

        // Trigger onScrollEnd manually on android
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            setImmediate(() => {
                this.onScrollEnd({
                    nativeEvent: {
                        position: diff
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Render ScrollView component
     * @param {array} slides to swipe through
     */
    renderScrollView = pages => {
        return (
            <ScrollView ref={component => { this.scrollView = component; }}
                {...this.props}
                contentContainerStyle={[styles.wrapper, this.props.style]}
                onScrollBeginDrag={this.onScrollBegin}
                onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onScrollEnd}
                onScrollEndDrag={this.onScrollEndDrag}
            >
                {pages.map((page, i) =>
                    // Render each slide inside a View
                    <View style={[styles.fullScreen, styles.slide]} key={i}>
                        {page}
                    </View>
                )}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

    /**
     * Render pagination indicators
     */
    renderPagination = () => {
        if (this.state.total <= 1) {
            return null;
        }

        const ActiveDot = <View style={[styles.dot, styles.activeDot]} />,
            Dot = <View style={styles.dot} />;

        let dots = [];

        for (let key = 0; key < this.state.total; key++) {
            dots.push(key === this.state.index
                // Active dot
                ? React.cloneElement(ActiveDot, { key })
                // Other dots
                : React.cloneElement(Dot, { key })
            );
        }

        return (
            <View
                pointerEvents="none"
                style={[styles.pagination, styles.fullScreen]}
            >
                {dots}
            </View>
        );
    }

    /**
     * Render the component
     */
    render = ({ children } = this.props) => {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, styles.fullScreen]}>
                {/* Render screens */}
                {this.renderScrollView(children)}
                {/* Render pagination */}
                {this.renderPagination()}
                {/* Render Continue or Done OnBoardingButton */}
                {this.renderOnBoardingButton()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // Set width and height to the screen size
    fullScreen: {
        width: width,
        height: height
    },
    // Main container
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        position: 'relative'
    },
    // Slide
    slide: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    // Pagination indicators
    pagination: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 110,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    // Pagination dot
    dot: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)',
        width: 8,
        height: 8,
        borderRadius: 4,
        marginLeft: 3,
        marginRight: 3,
        marginTop: 3,
        marginBottom: 3
    },
    // Active dot
    activeDot: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    // Button wrapper
    OnBoardingButtonWrapper: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        flex: 1,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 40,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
});
```

Comment: In what file you get this error? Where `swiper.js` is imported in your `App.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of React Navigation you are using?
Are you sure you have done set up correctly as they have changed the way to setup
react navigation since form version 3.?

try this...

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

//assuming you have OnBoardingRoutes as entry screen in App
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(OnBoardingRoutes);
```

then return AppContainer in your render method of App.js

```
return (
   <AppContainer />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix it using withNavigation